# What is hogging my Ethernet in Windows?

Tags: windows, performance, ethernet

The entire laptop is running slowly. It is new a few months ago, bit a Core i7 processor & 64gB RAM, both of which look ok on the task manager's performance tab. But Ethernet usage is spiking periodically. How can I discover what is causing this?

[image]

Comment: 568 kilobits is hardly that big a spike. Your main problem is likely that you have at least 1 CPU core pegged (solid 25% CPU use) and it is stuck at 0.78GHz which points at a thermal or power throttling event that has locked the system down. Try rebooting the system, fully removing power for a period and see if it returns.

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=0.78GHz

Comment: clicking on "open resource monitor" will likely show you exactly which processes have network activity

Comment: Full load on one CPU core, 30GB memory used and half load of GPU - if this is your PC idle condition, then you may have some coinmining process active?

Comment: No, just a major copy of a few Tb to an external USB ***2*** drive. But, upvote for a good suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To me it looks like the ethernet is not really an issue. The graph and value show 568kilobits which isn't particularly large. Brief spikes in traffic are not really an issue and the fact that the graph has not readjusted suggests that the spike is not much larger than what is seen.

My main concern is this:

[image]

You have at least 1 CPU core pegged and giving a solid 25% CPU use and [0.78GHz is a common speed for CPUs to be stuck at](https://superuser.com/search?q=0.78GHz) during a thermal or power throttling event that has locked the system down.

Often this is cleared either by rebooting, fully removing power for a period or otherwise clearing the CPU temperature issue.

If nothing else there is [ThrottleStop](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-throttlestop/) which can be used to bypass CPU throttling. I've seen a few indications that disabling `BD PROCHOT` should release your CPU throttle in a lot of cases but bear in mind that if your CPU (or chipset or GPU which all may contribute) is overheating then this could actually be a bad thing to do.

In the first instance I would be looking at the easy fixes of rebooting the system including chipset and thermal sensors by fully removing power.

Comment: You are probably fine,. If it is reasonably cool then it should carry on. I've heard a lot of laptops in the last few years which have good CPU temperatures but sound like the chipset thermal sensor contributes to a platform thermal throttle and seems like it actually refuses to release the throttle even after cooling down, though in your case the GPU looks like it might be contributing as well. The GPU use is probably Windows Defender doing virus scan on everything if you are copying files. Heavy USB and disk use could make chipsets hot

Comment: So I'd let it finish then try to clear the throttle and see if it does it again. If it throttles regularly then it might be that you need to open up the machine and clean fans and replace thermal pads.

Comment: So it sounds like there is *something* that is actively causing it to throttle rather than a poorly programmed firmware holding it out. I'd be tempted to fire up HWiNFO or Speedfan and see if there are any temperature sensors showing particularly high compared to the CPU.

Comment: I will do that as soon as I get home. Thanks again - muchly

Comment: Excellent spotting.  I'd also eyeball the CPU fan and any vents for dust blockage too.  A couple of months may be enough for filters to clog up and reduce airflow and therefore cooling, causing a thermal change.

Comment: If it is a case of "stuck" thermal sensors a BIOS update may help. I know of several  Siemens/Fujitsu i7 laptops (H700 and H770 models)  that suffered badly from this. New Bios reprogrammed the thermal controller to make the issue less frequent and the effect (when it did happen) less drastic.

Comment: Also, why is the memory on a constant 30GB use and only 25% cpu usage? Sure, could be legit, but it is quite suspicious.

Comment: ThrottleStop doesn't work on newer Intel CPUs because the ever-increasing power and thermal constraints simply preclude software control (which is slow), versus full on-chip hardware control which is able to react far faster to changes in operating conditions. As a side-effect, it means that the clueless hordes who undervolted their laptop CPUs with ThrottleStop without understanding what they're doing, can no longer cause BSoDs on their devices. So that particular spam from said hordes will stop appearing on tech support forums, which is nice.

Comment: @IanKemp I was under the impression that while ThrottleStop was now useless for undervolting, it was still useful for clearing `BD PROCHOT` which can unlock a throttling machine. Granted this should still be done with care and knowlege that everything really *is* fine as releasing that lockout on a machine with thermal issues can actually make things worse...

Comment: The power adapter could also be at issue. A coworker got the wrong power adapter for their laptop a while back: it'd charge the laptop and "run" it, but it was the wrong output voltage(?) so it'd throttle the CPU _hard_ while plugged in. Unplugging the power cable from the laptop removed the throttling.

Comment: @Mokubai Ah right, I was talking about FIVR. I personally would not play with PROCHOT because it can affect more than the CPU, and it's likely to be a temporary fix anyway because whatever's setting the flag will just set it back again. At the end of the day, the fix is for consumers to buy laptops with decent cooling, instead of expecting that the rubbish Macbook-style chassis that seem to be so prevalent will somehow be able to dissipate tens of watts of heat.

Answer (score 2):

Repeated ethernet activity is nothing to be concerned about. Nowadays there are all sorts of processes that are constantly accessing the internet (via your ethernet) for completely legitimate reasons. Windows Update is a prime example, as (sadly) are many drivers nowadays (or to be more precise, the bloatware that's bundled with the driver).

Basically, if it ain't broke, it doesn't need fixing (apart from the likely CPU throttling issue that the other answer has noted).

Answer (score -1):

I'd bet you are using Windows 10. If you are, I suggest you create a Dual-Boot system with Windows 8 & see if booting to Windows 8 has the same problem.

Open Task Manager to see exactly what is using the ethernet bandwidth.